# Printing out binary tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

*This question is regarding keeping track of recursion depth in a recursive function.*

I have an array `int inputArr[]` storing input values. I created a recursive function which rearranges the values from `int inputArr[]` into a binary tree structure according to these rules:

- every new left node is formed by taking the middle value of the lefthand side
- respectively for the right node
- if the number of the elements in the new subarray is even (hence there is no middle value), we take the right one from the two middle values

This is already taken care of by my `foo(from: to: )`.

We're printing out the values such that there are `n` spaces before each node and a dash (`n` is the depth of the tree).

I struggle with the printing. Storing the depth and then making `n` spaces based on `int depthArr[]` elements is just giving a wrong output.

Correct examples:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} -> {3, 2, 1, 4}

- 3
 - 2
  - 1
 - 4

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} -> {3, 2, 1, 5, 4}:

- 3
 - 2
  - 1
 - 5
  - 4

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} -> {5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 7, 6, 8}

- 5
 - 3
  - 2
   - 1
  - 4
 - 7
  - 6
  - 8

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} -> {4, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5}

- 4
 - 2
  - 1
  - 3
 - 6
  - 5
```

My function (just focus on the depth array, everything else works):

```
public void foo(int from, int to) {
    outputArr[index] = arr[getIndex(from, to)]; // Just saving the values in correct order
    depthArr[index++] = depth; // Trying out to keep track of current depth

    int prev = to;
    to = getIndex(from, to);

    if (from - to == 0) {
        depth--; // I think that I'm incorrectly decreasing the depth as the recursion goes back
        return;
    }

    depth++;
    foo(from, to - 1);

    if (prev - from != 1)
        foo(to + 1, prev);
}

public int getIndex(int from, int to) { // Get the middle value from, to
    int numOfElements = to - from + 1;
    return from + (numOfElements / 2);
}
```

Where `getIndex(from: , to: )` will just give me the index of the next middle value from some index to some index (the input array is public). For exmaple: `getIndex(0, 2)` from `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` is `2` and so on.

**Is there a way of printing out the tree in the correct order without even needing to store the depth? Or is there any easy and reliable way I overlooked?**

My output:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

- 3
 - 2
  - 1
 - 5
  - 4 // Correct



{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}

- 5
 - 3
  - 2
   - 1
  - 4
 - 7
  - 6
 - 8 // Should have one more space

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}

- 4
 - 2
  - 1
 - 3 // Should have one more space
- 6 // Should have one more space
 - 5
- 7 // Should have one more space
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved.**

The `int depth` was a static variable which caused the problem when returning back from the recursion since by the time the left nodes were finished and the depth was already subtracted, the `depthArr[]` tracked the subtracted depths on the same floor. Solution is to track the depths internally via argument:

```
    public void foo(int from, int to, int depth) {
    outputArr[index] = arr[getIndex(from, to)];
    depthArr[index++] = depth;

    int prev = to;
    to = getIndex(from, to);

    if (from - to == 0) {
        return;
    }

    foo(from, to - 1, depth + 1); // <-- here

    if (prev - from != 1)
        foo(to + 1, prev, depth + 1); // <-- here
}
```

Now we need call the function as `foo(0, inputArr.length, 0)` and everything will work.